# why the `stringify_list()` method does not return all the values?

Tags: python, oop, data-structures, linked-list, nodes

I am trying to get all of the values from the nodes using the `stringify_list()` and I succeeded, however, when the same method is executed in `try` it only fetches the value for the last node and not for other nodes.

```
class Node:
  def __init__(self, value, next_node=None):
    self.value = value
    self.next_node = next_node
    
  def get_value(self):
    return self.value
  
  def get_next_node(self):
    return self.next_node
  
  def set_next_node(self, next_node):
    self.next_node = next_node

  class LinkedList:
  def __init__(self, value=None):
    self.head_node = Node(value)
  
  def get_head_node(self):
    return self.head_node

  def insert_beginning(self, new_value):
    new_node = Node(new_value)
    new_node.set_next_node(self.head_node)
    self.head_node = new_node
    
  def stringify_list(self):
    values = "" 
    
    while self.get_head_node().get_next_node():
      values += str(self.get_head_node().get_value()) + "\n"
      self.head_node = self.get_head_node().get_next_node()
    values += str(self.get_head_node().get_value())
    return values


ll = LinkedList(5)
ll.insert_beginning(70)
ll.insert_beginning(5675)
ll.insert_beginning(90)
print(ll.stringify_list())
```

When calling `stringify_list()` method, it returns the values of all nodes:

```
90
5675
70
5
```

but when calling it from `try` block:

```
try:
  print(ll.stringify_list())

except TypeError as e:
  print(e)
```

It returns the value of the last node only:

```
5
```

Comment: Your `stringify_list` is deleting elements.

Comment: It has nothing to do with `try`. Since `stringly_list()` modifies the list, calling it twice produces different results.

Comment: Use local variables instead of reassigning `self.head_node`.